# rmdir (2) used for directory tree removal

Tags: filesystems, standards, system-calls, standards-compliance

If a particular filesystem supports cheap removal of whole directories (with everything inside), **would it be acceptable** by POSIX / Linux / de-facto standards to let `rmdir` syscall delete a directory successfully even if it was not empty?

Manpage for [rmdir(2) syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rmdir.2.html) specifies an error `ENOTEMPTY` can (or should?) be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the "official" spec, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//functions/rmdir.html , no. It clearly says

*"The directory shall be removed only if it is an empty directory.*,

and further

*If the directory is not an empty directory, rmdir() shall fail and set errno to [EEXIST] or [ENOTEMPTY].*.

Anyway, I suspect such a filesystem supporting cheap removal of whole directories is not POSIX-compliant, as a POSIX-compliant filesystem would need to inspect the link count of every file in the tree, making the operation not-that-cheap. So I suppose you could argue that since the filesystem isn't POSIX-compliant anyway, it can have some leeway in the syscall semantics as well..

Comment: I think Linux is not fully POSIX-compliant anyway.

Comment: @ArekBulski: Sure, Linux does a lot beyond the POSIX spec, and I'm sure you can find a large number of corner cases where the semantics differ from POSIX. But, not maintaining link counts for inodes is a pretty fundamental deviation from how Linux (and POSIX) filesystems tend to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is another reason why cheap recursive removal might not be possible to implement. File deep inside may not have permissions allowing to be removed even if top directory could be removed. It could work if files could only have less restrictive permissions than the parent, but that is another can of worms.